Javafx WebEngine javascript exception
In my JavaFX WebView application an upcall member is injected into the HTML document that will trigger an upcall to Java when certain SVG images are toggled by a mouse click.
 ( (JSObject)webEngine.executeScript( "window" ) )
            .setMember( "selector", this );

The document itself defines a script that toggles other SVG images on and off. This is called by
webEngine.executeScript("toggle(json)");
in response to the upcall.
The whole operation is invoked on the application thread. If I test the upcall by itself without invoking the script there is no problem. However, when invoking the script, the operation succeeds but a javascript error is generated to the effect that the upcall object is null. This seems to indicate an issue in WebView with having two javascript functions defined in the same file. Can anyone share experience with this issue?
